# Как устроен Instagram Activity or Fragment?

Tags: java, android, activity

Хотел понять/узнать как устроен инстаграм. Построен ли он на фрагментах или на активити и как правильно применять активити/фрагменты. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Инстаграм, как и все FB приложения, используют собственный SDK. https://mlsdev.com/blog/70-how-to-develop-an-app-like-instagram

Comment: Начните лучше изучение отсюда: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#0

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja спасибо большое